# React Native unable to resolve module from file

Tags: typescript, react-native

I'm trying to store all the CSS style values into one single `ts` file: `styles/base.ts`, and export those values in `styles/index.ts` file. 

But when I try to use import the value from `index.ts` in my `App.tsx` file, it says

> Unable to resolve module "styles/index" from "App.tsx": "styles/index"
>   could not be found within the project.`.

I'm not sure is it a correct way to manage the styles inside application. Can anyone help me?

Here is how my `base.ts` file looks like:

```
export const colors = {
  grey: "#E3E1D6",
  black: "#333333",
};
```

**index.ts:**

```
import * as BaseStyle from "./base";
export {BaseStyle};
```

**App.tsx:**

```
import React from "react";
import {StyleSheet, View, Text} from "react-native";
import {BaseStyle} from "styles/index";
const App = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <View style={styles.body}>
        <Text>Test</Text>
      </View>
    </>
  );
};
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  body: {
    backgroundColor: BaseStyle.colors.grey,
  },
});
export default App;
```

And here is my **package.json** looks like:

```
{
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.9.0",
    "react-native": "0.61.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.6.2",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.6.2",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^0.0.5",
    "@types/jest": "^24.0.18",
    "@types/react-native": "^0.60.22",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "16.9.0",
    "babel-jest": "^24.9.0",
    "jest": "^24.9.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.56.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.9.0",
    "typescript": "^3.6.3"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native",
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "ts",
      "tsx",
      "js",
      "jsx",
      "json",
      "node"
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's only a typo mistake in your import.
You should write:

```
import {BaseStyle} from "./styles/index";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create color class using this pattern

```
class Colors {
    static transparents = "#ffffff";
    static black = "#000";
}
export default Colors;
```

and you can import the color using this line

```
import Colors from './Colors';
```

Please follow this steps, this will help you 
its help me.

Comment: Hi, can you tell me what's the benefit to use Class instead of using const?

Comment: By create a class you can access all class variable by class name . variable name.

It is provide direct accessibility to the object/ variables